# Bit shift and byte to int conversions in F#

Tags: f#, xna, bitwise-operators, kinect

I am using the kinect to do a few things in F# but am having a little trouble working with depth data. I have been following this tutorial: http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/kinect-fundamentals-3-getting-data-from-the-depth-sensor/

which has c# examples which I have been trying to convert to F#.

This part of code is being problematic:

```
void kinectSensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
PlanarImage p = e.ImageFrame.Image;

    Color[] DepthColor = new Color[p.Height * p.Width];

    float maxDist = 4000;
    float minDist = 850;
    float distOffset = maxDist – minDist;

    kinectDepthVideo = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, p.Width, p.Height);

    int index = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < p.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < p.Width; x++, index += 2)
        {
            int n = (y * p.Width + x) * 2;
            int distance = (p.Bits[n + 0]  |  p.Bits[n + 1] << 8);
            byte intensity = (byte)(255 – (255 * Math.Max(distance – minDist, 0) / (distOffset)));
            DepthColor[y * p.Width + x] = new Color(intensity, intensity, intensity);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having appears to be with this part: `int distance = (p.Bits[n + 0]  |  p.Bits[n + 1] << 8);`

in F# his should become `let distance = (p.Bits.[n+0] ||| p.Bits.[n+1] <<< 8)`

this means, through type inferance that distance is of type "byte" which I then cast to an int like this: `let distance = int(p.Bits.[n+0] ||| p.Bits.[n+1] <<< 8)`.  is this the correct way to convert a bit to an int? Are my bitwise operations correct? As I have been learning F# from scratch myself I am unsure but this doesnt throw any syntax errors.

However, it does mean that all my depth measurements come out as 0.  If I have it as byte they are slightly more sensible but they dont work with the next line (this one is in c# but I do have an F# version of it... does the same thing!)`byte intensity = (byte)(255 – (255 * Math.Max(distance – minDist, 0) / (distOffset)));`

Essentially I cannot get it to do anything other than give me 255 for each output intensity.

Any help would be really appreciated and apologies for the obscure things I am trying to do! Should probably just use C#!

Thanks

Comment: Not sure offhand, but do try adding parens, e.g. `(x|||(y<<<8))`

Comment: Actually, you may need to widen to int before doing the ops, e.g. `((int x)|||((int y)<<<8)))` (not at a compiler to try it out myself now)

Comment: Thanks @Brian I saw the below answer before this but essentially the same yes? making sure it does the bitshift before the ||| using parenthesis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The snippet below shows that conversion from two adjacent `bytes` of `array` into `int` works right:

```
let bytes = [|1uy;1uy|]
let distance = int bytes.[0] ||| (int bytes.[1] <<< 8)
printfn "%08X" distance
00000101
val bytes : byte [] = [|1uy; 1uy|]
val distance : int = 257
```

Comment: Wonderfull, thank you! worked a treat! I see now what i did wrong- i think. am i right in thinking my code "p.Bits.[n+0] ||| p.Bits.[n+1] <<< 8" does the ||| first then the <<< to the whole lot. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Ewen: Operator precedence is only one part of the problem with your original code. The other equally important part of the problem is operand size: shifting `p.Bits.[n+1]` byte by 8 bits to the left without prior extending the `byte` into some wider type, will effectively loose all your original content, getting the result of 8 zero bits instead. Preserving the data requires extending the `byte` at least by another 8 bits to `uint16`, or better to `int`. Extending your right `byte` would require you to similarly extend your left `byte`.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes a lot of sense. The only other thing I am having trouble with is bit masking. I want to get the 3 lest significant bits of a byte. I cannot find much on google about this searching for logical masks or bit masks etc. in C# it is "byte && 0x07" but I cant get this in F#- "pImg.Bits.[n] &&& 0x07" (or 7 or 00000111). You have been a brilliant help so far, if you ahve any ideas about this, that would be great.  Thanks

Comment: The byte literal for extracting 3 lower bits is simply `7uy`. You may want to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233193(v=vs.110).aspx for F# literal types list.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and the link. Understand this now. Thanks!